# Calling my global operator delete through delete operator

Tags: c++, memory, operator-keyword, delete-operator

The new operator accepts arguments that it passes along with the size to allocate to the correct version of global operator new.

Does delete operator accept arguments too ?
If yes, how can I specify them ?

My global operator delete has arguments and I need that it is called.

Answer (score 3):

`operator delete` by default doesn't take any arguments other than the `void*` pointer to the memory to be deallocated. If you write a custom `operator new`, then you should write a matching `operator delete` with any extra parameters used by `operator new` because the language spec is such that if your custom `operator new` throws an exception, it will try to call the matching `operator delete` based on the signature. However, other than that, the parameters have no effect.

Hope this helps!